# Compile C++ with Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin

How do I compile my C++ programs in Cygwin. I have gcc installed. What command should I use? Also, how do I run my console application when it is in a .cpp extension. I am trying to learn C++ with some little programs, but in Visual C++, I don't want to have to create a seperate project for each little .cpp file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use a command like:

```
g++ -o prog prog.cpp
```

That's a simple form that will turn a one-file C++ project into an executable. If you have multiple C++ files, you can do:

```
g++ -o prog prog.cpp part2.cpp part3.cpp
```

but eventually, you'll want to introduce makefiles for convenience so that you only have to compile the bits that have changed. Then you'll end up with a `Makefile` like:

```
prog: prog.o part2.o part3.o
    g++ -o prog prog.o part2.o part3.o

prog.o: prog.cpp
    g++ -c -o prog.o prog.cpp

part2.o: part2.cpp
    g++ -c -o part2.o part2.cpp

part3.o: part3.cpp
    g++ -c -o part3.o part3.cpp
```

And *then*, you'll start figuring how to write your makefiles to make them more flexible (such as not needing a separate rule for each C++ file), but that can be left for another question.

Regarding having a separate project for each C++ file, that's not necessary at all. If you've got them all in one directory and there's a simple mapping of C++ files to executable files, you can use the following makefile:

```
SRCS=$(wildcard *.cpp)
EXES=$(SRCS:.cpp=.exe)

all: $(EXES)

%.exe: %.cpp
    g++ -o $@ $^
```

Then run the `make` command and it will (intelligently) create all your executables. `$@` is the target and `$^` is the list of pre-requisites.

And, if you have more complicated rules, just tack them down at the bottom. Specific rules will be chosen in preference to the pattern rules:

```
SRCS=$(wildcard *.cpp)
EXES=$(SRCS:.cpp=.exe)

all: $(EXES)

%.exe: %.cpp
    g++ -o $@ $^

xx.exe: xx.cpp xx2.cpp xx3.cpp
    g++ -o $@ $^
    echo Made with special rule.
```

Comment: Thanks. But can I create a single makefile that compiles any C++ file in the same directory instead of creating a makefile for each specific .cpp file?

Comment: What is the extension? .make? Or no extension like myMakefile

Comment: @Mohit, those makefiles do compile any cpp file to it's equivalent exe (the wildcard and the '%' pattern see to that). By convention the make file is called Makefile or makefile. You can use a different name like bob.mk but then you have to do 'make -f bob.mk all' instead of just 'make all'.

Answer (score 4):

You will need g++. Then try `g++ file.cpp -o file.exe` as a start. Later you can avoid much typing by learning about Makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use cygwin you should use the normal `gcc` syntax

```
g++ -o foobar foobar.cpp
```

but that doesn't really play well with Visual C++. I advise you to take a look into [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) if you prefer using GCC over the visual C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to compile a cpp program:

```
g++ -Wall Test.cpp -o Test
-Wall enables warning and error messages to be shown 
-o Test creates an Test.exe after compilation
```

If you want to compile files separately:

```
g++ -Wall -c File1.cpp
g++ -Wall -c File2.cpp
```

Now create an executable with the combined object files as:

```
g++ -Wall File1.o File2.o  -o File.exe
```

This way you can compile your header files and you can include in your application programs.