# what command on cmd works just the same as the "makefiles" command on Linux?

Tags: windows, makefile, command, cmd, prompt

I'm new on C programming and I had been wondering what command on cmd works just the same as makefiles on Linux. You see, the OS of the computers we use in school is Linux and Mac and my laptop is Windows 8 and so the text editor I use is only Notepad++. I started coding just a few weeks from now and I'm going crazy since I got something to hand in and I cannot figure out what command to use. Plus, I do not have Visual Studio or whatsoever installed on my computer. It might just be a simple problem for you guys so someone help me?

So the basic `HelloWorld.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
printf("HelloWorld\n");
return 0;
}
```

to compile: gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld -Wall
to run: HelloWorld

@Beta That's how I do it on Windows

Comment: You could [install Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and then [compile C++ with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753239/compile-c-with-cygwin) or whatever your favorite compiler is. You'd also have access to `make`. Or you could just get a simple IDE.

Comment: What is this command named `makefiles`? What compiler are you using on Windows? How to you want to go about compiling your code?

Comment: Are you familiar with `HelloWorld`?

Comment: @Beta what do you mean 'familiar'? You mean some sample program people always use?

Comment: Yes! A good first step with a new tool or on a new system is to write, compile and run `HelloWorld`. Can you do that (without a makefile)? If so, how? If not, which step fails?

Comment: All right, edit your question to tell us how you did it. Then we'll see if you have `Make` installed, and construct a makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, so good. Now try `make -v`, to determine whether you have Make installed, and if so which version.

**EDIT:**

All right, let's try a very simple makefile:

```
all:
    @echo hello
```

This is just a text file called `makefile`. The whitespace at the beginning of the second line is a TAB, *not* spaces. (I'll explain the '@' later.) Once you have written this file, try `make`. It should say `hello`.

Comment: Agh, wait. I think I do. when I used it, something popped on the cmd. soome MingW32 stuff. @Beta

Comment: @Sakamoto: You can take it from here? Or do you need more help?

Comment: Wait, so let me get this straight. I'll make a file called makefile where all:<enter><tab>@echo hello is written. Then I'd write make on the command line? just checking if i got it right

Comment: @Sakamoto: Yes, that's right. And you must be in the directory where that file is.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need some tools to get your code done.

Option 1:
You said you don't have visual studio, did that mean you wanted it?

Microsoft offers Visual Studio Express for free, I have a 2010 version that I use when I need to reproduce something on there, but there's a [2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-products) version listed as well.

---

Option 2:
You said you have Windows but they use Linux at your school? Well have you ever heard of [Oracle's VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)? It's a very simple application that lets you run a Linux box inside your windows machine, and it's free! Go to Oracle's site and download VirtualBox then go to the site of your favorite Linux distro and download a .iso image of it (for example if you were feeling Minty you could go get a iso here)

Then you can follow the instructions to set up and "install" the iso in the virtual machine and voila! You have Linux at home. Gcc/Make and everything you're used to.

---

Option 3:

If you just want Make GCC and such tools you can get them from the [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) site. You can set things in your windows environment variables such that you can call `gcc` and `make` right from the command prompt wherever it is.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, yeah, maybe I'll try VirtualBox next time.