# Terminal will not create .exe file for C++ file?

Tags: c++, terminal

I have attached image of my compiler. My cygwin terminal will not create .exe file for my C++ program? I do not see exe file in my project diretory. I have used cygwin to compile code before, so I do not understand why it does not work.

VScode does the same thing as well?

Does anyone know a possible solution?

Comment: The image appears to be missing, but at StackOverflow, including images tends to be discouraged.

Comment: For starters, can you tell us how you are attempting to compile your code. Include what you are typing (or what vscode is producing) when attempting to compile your source. Also see [Compile C++ with Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753239/compile-c-with-cygwin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile C++ with Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753239/compile-c-with-cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the full version of Visual Studios works much better than VS Code for compiling EXE's. You can get it for free here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

Comment: Only downside is the 4-8 Gigabytes of hard drive storage required to install VisualStudio, but I agree it does work quite well. As do cygwin or MinGW using `g++`.